# Is using the same key for different message HMACs insecure?

Tags: encryption, hmac

When using the `MAC-then-Encrypt` composition, would using the same key for the HMAC in each different message be insecure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, with a reasonable choice of hash function, HMAC can safely authenticate many messages under the same key—it is not a *one-time* MAC like GHASH or Poly1305.  Of course, it may be prudent to use a *message sequence number* so you can reject replays (and it may be necessary for your encryption scheme, *e.g.* if you're using AES-CTR or ChaCha).

That said, why are you making this decision instead of using an authenticated cipher like AES-GCM or NaCl crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305?

Comment: The reason for not an authenticated encryption mode is I agree with Colin Percival's opinion on those - which you probably know. Also, I use `SHA3_256` as my hash.

Comment: If you're referring to [Colin Percival's ‘cryptographic right answers’](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html), that was written over a decade ago before authenticated ciphers like AES-GCM and crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305 were widely available.  (What he called ‘CWC’ in his [expanded note](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-24-encrypt-then-mac.html) is a predecessor to GCM, and NaCl had just been released the year prior.)  His point about side channel attacks is relevant for AES-GCM in software; not so much for crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305.

Comment: Side note: There is essentially [no technical reason to ever use SHA3-256 for anything](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70582) because its kind of goofy parameters were chosen for political rather than technical reasons, and no reason to use HMAC with SHA-3 when you can use KMAC128 instead.

Comment: Ok then - he links to an article that is more up-to-date and he mentions gcm in that. Anyway, the associated data is a nuisance in my program, and HMACs serve me better. What is your recommended hash?

Comment: If associated data is a nuisance then just…don't use it.  You can safely pass in an empty string as the associated data.  For authenticated encryption, I recommend NaCl crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305 (unless you have constraints—which you don't seem to have—to use US federal government standards, in which case AES-GCM).  If you _really really_ want to use SHA-3, just use KMAC128 with a 128-bit output.  If for some reason you have some of SHA-3 but not KMAC, SHAKE128(key ∥ msg) with 256-bit key and 128-bit output is perfectly fine as a MAC too.

Comment: To be clear, HMAC-SHA3256 doesn't make a _bad_ MAC.  It's just a rather silly way of doing things that can be done much more simply and efficiently—like using two pairs of tongs to manipulate a pair of tongs to pick up and move a carrot when you can just grab the carrot with your hand.  It was basically a design goal of SHA-3 was to make HMAC unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use SHAKE where possible. Also, how secure is SHA256?

Comment: SHA-256 provides collision resistance and (second-)preimage resistance at a 128-bit security level (and (second-)preimage resistance at a ‘256-bit’ security level, but that level is essentially meaningless).  It can be reasonably modeled as a random oracle _except_ for the usual length extension issue.  It's a reasonable choice for HMAC.  Overall, we have no reason to doubt the standard security claims advertised for SHA-256.